# setImageResource taking more space than original

Tags: android, imagebutton, imagesource

onClick I am changing `imageSource` on a `ImageButton`
Originally it is like(see heart Icon)[image]
after i change imageSource programmatically using `search.setImageResource(R.drawable.linked);` it looks like 
[image]

```
 <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/favrouite"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_fav"
        />
```

Yet Both the Images of same size on appllying programmatically differ
How can i resolve this Issue?
Please Help
Regards

Comment: are you sure that the two images have the exact same size and also put in the same drawable folder?

Comment: yes both 48 x 48 pixels

Comment: if you are set this Image in `Toolbar` then Notice one thing you have to use `24*24` icon size.

Comment: no there are in a custom ListView

Comment: share the code that does this change?

Comment: i have already added it in the question `search.setImageResource(R.drawable.linked);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess both image **resolution** are not same.Check your both image resolutions.

Comment: they are same sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
ImageView lineColorCode =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.line_color_code);
int color = Color.parseColor("#AE6118"); //The color u want             
lineColorCode.setColorFilter(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with different scaletypes. Ex:
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:scaleType="fitcenter"
...

Answer (score -1):

you need to add padding again when you set image resource dynamically. Add padding dynamically when you are setting imageresource